# Is there anyway to pull multiple pictures from an excel sheet at once on my ubuntu

Tags: command-line, automation, curl

I have this task which will take me forever to finish, about 1000 rows in an excel sheet of pictures names and links in different two columns (1st &3rd columns).

i was thinking if i could use curl to automate the process and if there’s any other trick or tool to pull these pictures links to be downloaded in a file on my system and also have them named respectively as they’re named in the first column.

Note : all the pictures are in imgur links that i have personally uploaded on imgur and pasted on excel which took me forever i was hoping i’ll be able to find a smarter way this time.

Any help us really appreciate it

Comment: Why would this not work? https://askubuntu.com/a/224768/15811

Answer (score 0):

In Libreoffice Calc, you can concatenate strings with the `&` operator. For example, a formula such as

```
"curl "&"A3"&" "A1"
```

would create a string like `curl contentsA3 contentsA3`.

Thus, you could construct the needed command to download the graphic under the desired name using this approach in e.g. the fourth column. Paste the resulting strings from the fourth column into a plain text file, and in the terminal, source the text file to have all commands executed. To source the file:

```
source myfile.txt
```

or shortly:

```
. myfile.txt
```

Alternatively, if you are more familiar with [bash text processing](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/textproc.html), you could copy out column 1 and column 3 to separate text files, and combine these two into a new file containing the correct commands using tools like.

I obviously leave it to you to find the correct `curl` command to download a file from an URL to a specific file name.